# django (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')

Tags: django, migrate

recently when in want to migrate my model I encountered this error in django:
"(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')"

```
 class PartCategory(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField("نام",max_length = 50)
        code=models.CharField("کد",max_length = 50,unique=True)
        description=models.CharField("توضیحات",max_length = 50)
        priority=models.IntegerField("اولویت", null=True)

        isPartOf = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="زیر مجموعه",null=True,blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        class Meta:
           db_table = "partcategory"
```

Comment: have you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and after `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: yes but still face the problem

Comment: you can try to delete all your migrations and do it again.

Comment: I did it but problem still remains